# Using arrows to annotate a tkz-euclide picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm using tkz-euclide to draw figures for my students to fill-out.
I'm trying to reproduce this figure, but I have no idea how to make the arrows pointing to the different elements and the dots for them to write.

[image: Image to fill]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzActivOff
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B}
    \tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
    \tkzDefPoint(70:4){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(110:4){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(170:4){F}
    \tkzDefPoint(250:4){D}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A,F)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](E,C)
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](D){$D$}
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=blue](C,D)
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=orange](A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=green](E,F)
    \tkzDrawArc[color=red](A,E)(F)
    \tkzActivOn
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `tkz-euclide` works inside `tikzpicture` environment, you can use the normal `tikz` commands to draw arrows and add additional information. I've added some arrows to your pictures, just copy/paste/modify as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzActivOff
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B}
    \tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
    \tkzDefPoint(70:4){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(110:4){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(170:4){F}
    \tkzDefPoint(250:4){D}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A,F)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](E,C)
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](D){$D$}
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=blue](C,D)
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=orange](A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=green](E,F)
    \tkzDrawArc[color=red](A,E)(F)
    \tkzActivOn
    \draw[<-, orange, shorten < = 0.3cm] (2,0) -- (5,3) node[at end, right] {Notation:};
    \draw[<-, red, shorten < = 0.3cm] (135:4) -- (135:6) node[at end, left] {Notation:};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```